# How many inscribed square in ellipses there exist?

Tags: calculus, euclidean-geometry

How many inscribed square in ellipses there exist?

I think there exist only one square. Is this true? Is there a proof?

Comment: [Related](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/3j98wu/can_an_square_be_inscribed_in_every_single_ellipse/) (**not** Math.SE link).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the inscribed square is unique provided the ellipse is non-degenerate .

Given a non-degenerate ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ with $a > b > 0$, let $(p,q)$ be the center of a non-degenerate square inscribed in it.
Since the square is non-degenerate, we can find two numbers $u,v$, not both zero, such that the vertices of the squares are located at
$$(p+u,q+v),\quad (p-v,q+u),\quad (p-u,q-v),\quad (p+v,q-u)$$
Since these vertices lie on the ellipse, we have

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(p+u)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(q+v)^2}{b^2} &= 1\tag{*1}\\
\frac{(p-v)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(q+u)^2}{b^2} &= 1\tag{*2}\\
\frac{(p-u)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(q-v)^2}{b^2} &= 1\tag{*3}\\
\frac{(p+v)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(q-u)^2}{b^2} &= 1\tag{*4}
\end{align}
$$
Notice
$$\begin{align}
(*1) - (*3) &\leadsto \frac{up}{a^2} + \frac{vq}{b^2} = 0\\
(*2) - (*4) &\leadsto \frac{-vp}{a^2} + \frac{uq}{b^2} = 0
\end{align}
\quad\iff\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
u & v \\
-v & u
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \frac{p}{a^2} \\ \frac{q}{b^2} \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Now $u,v$ are not both zero, the $2\times 2$ matrix appeared in RHS has to be invertible. This forces $(p,q) = (0,0)$. The center of the square coincides with the center of ellipse. Furthermore, the four equations reduce to

$$\frac{u^2}{a^2} + \frac{v^2}{b^2} = \frac{v^2}{a^2} + \frac{u^2}{b^2} = 1$$

Since $a > b > 0$, this leads to $|u| = |v|$. The inscribed square is unique and its vertices can be constructed by intersecting the ellipse with the pair of lines $y \pm x  = 0$.