# About the construction of quadrate on oval

Tags: 3d, geometric-construction

[image]

I've done constructing the oval, but now I'm having trouble drawing a square on it. What should I do about this? (The three points given inside the oval are two focuses and the midpoint of the focuses.)

I've tried drawing the meet of the focus-point line and oval(like this...)
[image]

But this has no reason, and I think it doesn't work...

Another thing I've thought about is drawing a square first and minimize it to the oval, but I don't have any idea to do like that.

Comment: 1) A more correct title would be : "How to inscribe a square into an ellipse (construction using ruler and compass)". In particular,  "oval" is a more "fuzzy" term than "ellipse". 2) You say that your ellipse is given by its foci, but this is not sufficient: there is an infinite number of ellipses with the same foci ; you need an extra information (another point for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find plainly the 4 vertices of the square by intersecting the ellipse with the 2 angular bissectors of the symmetry axes of the ellipse (in other terms lines with equations $y=x$ and $y=-x$ when $x$ and $y$ coordinate axes are the symmetry axes), all constructions involved (including the construction of the $y$ axis) being evidently possible by ruler and compass.

In this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2493400/305862) it is proven that no other inscribed square exists.

Comment: Oh, this is an answer to another question... Anyway, this also helps solve the problem. My question was "
How do I draw a quadrangle on an ellipse so that it looks like a square when viewed three-dimensionally?".

Comment: I hadn't guessed at all that the question was this one. In fact, any parallelogram inscribed into an ellipse can be represented as the orthogonal projection of a square inscribed into a circle placed into a certain more or less inclined plane.

Comment: Oh, this comment gave me the answer... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just for showing my success with the answer above:

[image]